# Wordpress Loop Group every two posts

Tags: wordpress

I am looking out for some solution to wrap two posts each in a group.

Example group will be like this:

```
<div class="group1">
 - Post Title 1
 - Post Title 2
</div>
<div class="group2">
- Post Title 3
- Post Title 4
</div>
<div class="group1">
 - Post Title 5
 - Post Title 6
</div>
<div class="group2">
- Post Title 7
- Post Title 8
</div>
```

Kindly advise me a good solution.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use this, call `the_post()` inside the loop to time to execute two post in each loop.

```
$inc_tmp=1;
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="group<?php echo $inc_tmp;?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); /*  Advance onto the next post, and set the global $post variable. */?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $inc_tmp++;
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Update: if you are using default query then follow this code

```
$inc_tmp=1;
// The Loop
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="group<?php echo $inc_tmp;?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_post(); /*  Advance onto the next post, and set the global $post variable. */?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
        $inc_tmp++;
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want to execute set of posts as this is not a custom query but the main blog page of website.

Comment: @HimanshuJain There must be a loop , if it is the blog page then you are using default query. correct  me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes mate I am using default loop but the question is how should I group set of 2 posts each in the loop and we have two kind of groups here, group1 and group2 each having two posts each.

Comment: @HimanshuJain How you are defining your group? using tags or category? or any other meta value?

Comment: I am not creating groups right now, just want to wrap the posts within divs as shown in example.

Comment: In this query I will get the div class to be Group1, Group2, Group3, Group4 and so on.... but I need the groups to be alternating like Group1 -> Group2 -> Group1 -> Group2.